# Echo each time other string in php?

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array of strings how do I echo one by one at refresh

```
 session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["names"])){
    $_SESSION["names"] = $_SESSION["names"] + 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION["names"] = 1;
}

    $names = array("Adrian","Bill","Mac","John");

   echo $_SESSION["names"];
```

My code is messy just for example .I need to echo each time new name but not random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if(isset($_SESSION["names"])){
       $_SESSION["names"] = $_SESSION["names"] + 1;
   }
   else{
       $_SESSION["names"] = 0;
   }

   $names = array("Adrian","Bill","Mac","John");

   echo $names[$_SESSION["names"] % count($names)];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["echoedNames"])) {
$_SESSION["echoedNames"] = array();
}

while (!in_array($randomName = $names[rand(0, count($names))], $echoedNames) {
echo $randomName;
$_SESSION["echoedNames"][] = $randomName;
}
```

Or something like this.. Basically two arrays, one with already shown names and check if was shown before echo...

Comment: OP said, he doesn't want random names.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, I thought he meant not random but random from not shown before.. my bad